# CodeIgniter form validation helper always false

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am working with Codeigniter and on top of it I have Bonefire (could this be the problem?), problem is everytime I want to validate the form with the use of Codeigniters helpers first condition of my conditional runns (FALSE) and on top of that function `validation_errors()` isn't ran... It is like my libraries for this helper aren't even loaded, despite doing everything by the book:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{          
    echo $msg = validation_errors();
}
else
{       
    $this->load->user_model->insert($data);
    echo $msg = "Registration successfull";
}
```

Let me post my form first (I ommited inline styles and classes by purpose):

```
<div class="" style="">
    <h1 id="header" class="">Login/Register</h1>
    <form action="/public/index.php/users/sportappregister" >
        <div style=""><input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="email"  style=""></div>
        <div style=""><input id="pass" type="text" name="password" value="password"  style=""></div>
        <div style="" class=""><img class="" style="" src="<?php echo img_path(); ?>ikone/fb_login_icon.png" />Login with Facebook</div>
        <div id="send" style="" class=""><input type="submit"> Submit </div>
        <div id="cancel" style="" class=""> Cancel </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And as you can read from form action my controller is located in file "users" under public class "sportappregister", `class Users extends Front_Controller` as usuall and in this class at the end I make my own function to handle form like so:

```
public function sportappregister(){

    $email= ($this->input->get("email"));
    $pass = ($this->input->get("password"));

    $data = array(
              "email" => $email,
              "password" => $pass );

    // here I load my helper            
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // rules for my form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        echo $msg = validation_errors();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->user_model->insert($data);
        echo $msg = "Registration successfull";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You are using `GET` method. codeigniter form validation works with `POST` method only.

use CI form tags such as `form_open()` `form_close()` etc. to build form.
you can check [**This link**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

using get for login form will make your app insecure.

rest of your code seems ok to me.
just change this

```
$email= ($this->input->post("email")); //changed get to post in both
$pass = ($this->input->post("password"));
```

Comment: using post instead of get and the controller doesn't receive my input values! Is it neccessary to use form helper as I really don't feel comfortable using it?

Comment: @LazyPeon then add `<form action="/public/index.php/users/sportappregister" method="POST">` here. if CSRF is enabled you will have trouble since you are making form manually and not inserting hidden CSRF field.

Comment: yeah I have problems, now I get the php error: "The action you have requested is not allowed." What is CSRF?

Comment: @LazyPeon thats what i was talking its due to CSRF. add this in your form `<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->csrf_token_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->csrf_hash; ?>" />`

Comment: I get "Undefined property: MY_Security::$csrf_hash", do you mind explaining what are we doing here?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things I would change. Read the comments in the amended function below;

```
      public function sportappregister()
      {
                // Load these first
                $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                // Now set the rules
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Username', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

                if ( $this->form_validation->run() == false )
                {
                          echo validation_errors();
                }
                else
                {
                          // Build the array after the form validation
                          $data = array(
                                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'), // POST, not GET
                                    'password' => $this->input->post('password')
                          );

                          // Load your model
                          $this->load->model('users_model');
                          if ( $this->users_model->insert($data) )
                          {
                                    echo 'Registration successful';
                          }
                          else
                          {
                                    echo 'Registration failed';
                          }
                }
      }
```

You have also loaded the form helper, but you're not using it. It makes building forms much, much easier.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

```
<?php echo form_open('users/sportappregister'); ?>
```

Comment: using post instead of get and the controller doesn't receive my input values! Is it neccessary to use form helper in order for post to work, as I really don't feel comfortable using it?

Comment: This may be because your form isn't set to POST. Why do you feel uncomfortable using the form helper? I use it in all my CI applications, without any sort of problems.

Comment: I will use it from now on, also my problem is gone. Thanks both of you for your help!